# Considerations when picking a socket recv buffsize

Tags: python, sockets, unix

What are the benefits and drawbacks of choosing a buffsize that is larger (or smaller) than needed when working with sockets?

Consider my specific case as an example, I am using UNIX stream sockets in python to implement basic IPC for an app I am working on. There is one "server" process, and many "client" processes. The client processes connect to the server process's socket and send it commands. The server process receives those commands and executes them. The protocol they use is very simple, and the only notable rule is that each command must end with a semicolon.

The clients can send as many or as few commands as they'd like in each message (even a partial command, where the rest of the command and the accompanying semicolon are included in a future message). The server processes and stores messages in a queue until it receives a semicolon, then it saves the completed command to a queue.

The point of describing my simple example is to illustrate that in terms of information transfer, the buffsize argument passed to socket.recv() is completely irrelevant. i.e. I can call socket.recv(1) or socket.recv(1024) and the program's behavior doesn't change.

In situations like this, where the buffsize has no role in the overall execution of the underlying application, what is a good way to choose this value? What are some important things to consider when making this decision?

Comment: Your question is possibly the best I've seen of its type. The answer is "it depends" and bigger isn't always better. This is a FAQ. Try googling "socket receive buffer size".

Comment: Also, this is the type of question that depends on a huge number of variables such as the OS and the average size of each message. You can start with a reasonable default such as 32 kb and vary the value and measure how your specific application behaves.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It doesn’t seem to be requesting opinions - the listing the benefits and drawbacks associated with socket receive buffer sizes should be fairly objective, should it not?

Comment: The answer is indeed 'bigger is always better', subject to you overall memory allocation and resource sharing of course, but in practice unless you're slow in reading you probably won't receive more than about 1500 bytes at a time, i.e. the path MTU. What you should be paying attention to is not the `recv()` buffer but the socket receive buffer size, set by `SO_RCVBUFSIZ`, which in general you should set much larger than the default, to encourage maximum transfer speed from the peer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about the byte-count argument you pass to each `recv()` call (and not the size of the kernel's internal receive-buffer that is associated with the socket, and optionally changed via `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)`), then it is largely a matter of taste.

The advantage of passing a larger value to `recv()` is that you may be able to receive more bytes of data at once, and therefore you may need to call `recv()` a smaller number of times in order to collect the same amount of data.  This can improve CPU-efficiency somewhat by reducing the per-byte overhead of the data transfer.

The advantage of passing a smaller value to `recv()` is that you can reduce the worst-case amount of RAM required by the `recv()` call, since the argument limits the number of bytes of storage that `recv()` might need to return in a single array.

Modern computers have powerful enough CPUs and enough RAM that in most cases it's unlikely to make a measurable difference what value you choose.  In those few remaining cases where maximizing performance *is* important, choosing a larger recv-size is likely to perform better, although passing a size-value larger than the size of the socket's `SO_RCVBUF` buffer is unlikely to make any difference, since the kernel won't be able to hand you more bytes than it can store at once anyway.